# Google App Engine login URL redirect phonegap

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, cordova, google-signin

I am writing a Cordova (PhoneGap) application that uses a Google App Engine backend for logins and a database. Google App Engine seems to be structured to handle all URLs within the application, but that's not how Cordova does things. I am using `users.create_login_url()` to direct users to Google's login page. The first argument for this function is a redirect URL either to a full URL or a location relative to the application. I could enter `'/home'` or some URL like `'http://google.com'` but I want the application to redirect back to the Cordova page I was on when the user clicked the button to login. I entered `'http://localhost'` but I'm not sure this will work the way I'm expecting it to. Will this work, or do I need to do something else?

Essentially, I make the request for a login using jQuery.ajax():

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'http://localhost:8090/login', //I am running this in the GAE developer runtime
    success:function(data) {
        window.location = data;
    }
});
```

The above code should call the post() method in the Login class I have created in GAE. The code in that method does this:

```
def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        self.response.write("userAlreadyLoggedIn")
    else:
        self.response.write(users.create_login_url("http://localhost")
```

I haven't tested this yet, but ignoring any unrelated errors I may have had, will this do what I described above?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to redirect rather then write the log in URL to the response object.

```
self.redirect("/home")
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/redirects

Also the webapp2 documentation is worth a look:

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.redirect